# Deleting an object of an Abstract Class in program

Tags: java, abstract

I'm making a trading program, and lets say we have User which is an abstract class, and then we have Shareholder which extends User and we also have Admin which extends User. Lets say the Admin can deleteUser(User user). I can't figure out how this makes sense, how can we delete a User when we cannot instantiate a User.

I don't have any code right now I'm just making a class diagram for this and just got confused by this. But for the sake of this question, I'll add some little code:

```
public abstract class User{
  private String username;
  private String password;
}


public class Shareholder extends User{
  private double balance;
  #constructor to follow + setter and getter
}

public class Admin extends User{
  public void deleteUser(User user){..}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out how this makes sense, how can we delete a User
>   when we cannot instantiate a User.

Both `Admin` and `Shareholder` extend `User`. Instances of `Admin` and `Shareholder` are instances of `User`. When you instantiate the concrete classes `Admin` and `Shareholder` you are instantiating instances of `User`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [*is-a*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship, which is the base of inheritance, any subclass of `User` is also an `User` under all effects.

So, even assuming `User` can't be instantiated as a `User`, any subclass that is no more `abstract` can and they are `User` too.